# Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter at FsReadStream.close

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, html5-video

I added video on my react app and it started giving this error. Earlier it was working fine.

```
<video autoPlay>
          {" "}
          <source src={videoBg} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Error -

```
webpack 5.68.0 compiled successfully in 5293 ms
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property closed of #<Readable> which has only a getter
    at FsReadStream.close (D:\BTech\VSCode\house-of-arts\frontend\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:2047:17)
    at FsReadStream._destroy (D:\BTech\VSCode\house-of-arts\frontend\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:2032:10)
    at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:109:10)
    at class_1.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:71:5)
    at class_1.<anonymous> (D:\BTech\VSCode\house-of-arts\frontend\node_modules\memfs\lib\volume.js:1962:22)
    at class_1.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)        
Emitted 'error' event on class_1 instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```